# “Unexpected error on server associating the workflow”, when i define multiple If statement inside my workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have created the following workflow inside SharePoint designer:-

[image] d

now when i check the workflow for errors it mentioned that there are no errors, but when i try publishing the workflow i got the following error.

*“Unexpected error on server associating the workflow”*

baring in mind that i use to publish the workflow without any problems ,but after adding the extra two If statements i start getting the error.
can anyone advice ?
Regards

Comment: How can we see the detail of error?